# Unexpected line by zebra printer

Tags: java, android, adt, zebra-printers

I'm using Zebra printer and Android. This line

```
printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
```

make a printer to print unexpected line

```
U1 getvar "appl.name"
```

After that printer going well. How to get rid of printing that line?

Comment: We need additional data to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your printer is in line_print mode, instead of ZPL or CPCL mode.

If your printer is in line_mode, the SDK will not work. You can still use the communications classes, but the printer helper functions will not work in line_print mode.

If you don't want to be in line print mode, you can change the printer's language by sending the following command :

> SGD.DO("device.languages", "zpl", printerConnection)